# Command Line Tool Core Data Tutorial

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data

I'm playing with Xcode and Objective-C/Cocoa again. This time I want to start with the bare minimum. I would like to setup Core Data in something as simple as a Command Line Tool (if it's even possible.) I need some practice saving and retrieving data without the all the View Controllers and AppDelegate stuff. Any ideas or maybe I'm going about this all wrong?

Comment: I don’t see why this question has been closed, and mostly by people with no Cocoa experience on Stack Overflow. In other languages/libraries, it would be akin to asking how to create a database, insert a record, edit a record, and retrieve a record. It is a valid question since there is probably no reference showing how to do this in a command-line application.

Comment: If you create a new Xcode project from the "Command Line Tool" template and choose "Core Data" as type in the next step then you will get a main.c including the Core Data setup.

Comment: I did that and all I see is code. I'll keep looking through the Interwebs. I want to know "what for" and "why" a procedure is used. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

Your task will be the same as for any other project, except that the Command Line Tool template probably doesn't contain a Core Data option. No matter, you're doing this to learn, so setting up Core Data yourself won't hurt a bit.

Just create a new command line tool project and add a new Core Data model to the project. Next, you'll add the code that gets the model, creates a persistent store coordinator, uses those to create a managed object context. Then you can add objects, fetch objects, whatever you like.

Comment: It is not that simple, i noticed that .momd is not embedded in the executable, so if you move the executable to bin it will crash. If you run it from xcode is fine because the .momd is along the executable in the build folder